# iText "not found as file or resource" error

Tags: java, itext

I am getting issue "`<file_name>.pdf not found as file or resource`" The code uploads file from the path selected to database. Below is the code I used:
It reads the PDF file and uploads to DB as CLOB. It should be simple task however, for some reason it's not working.

```
public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public FileUpload() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doPost(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String uploadData="";
         BusinessLogic bl=new BusinessLogic();
         String user=(String) request.getSession().getAttribute("UserName");
         //InputStream inputStream = null;  

         String fileName = request.getParameter("file");
         File file = new File(fileName);
         try {
           // Load an existing document
             PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);            
             int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
             /*for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
             {*/
                 /*String str=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);*/
             String str=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2);
             uploadData=uploadData+str;
             /*}*/
             bl.updateAckFile(file,uploadData,user);

         } catch (Exception  e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
         }

         /*File file = new File(fileName);
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
         bl.updateAckFile(file,fis,user);*/
         RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/AcknowFile.jsp");        
         rd.forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: How do you ensure that the file path and name in the request parameter `file` denotes a pdf file on the server?

Comment: As of now I am ensuring I am selecting PDF file only. I'll handle non-PDF handling later. Still it's in test phase.

Comment: And the PDF is on the server? After all it is a request parameter from the client...

Comment: No it's in local desktop. One has to browse and upload.

Comment: *"One has to browse and upload."* - And does that happen? At least it is not happening in the code you show.